# warning of gyp in npm while installing angularcli EACCES?

Tags: node.js, angular

when trying to install angular cli with the command

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

it seems to caught up in an error loop with the below message

```
gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp"
gyp verb tmpdir == cwd automatically will remove dev files after to save disk space
gyp verb command install [ '8.9.4' ]
gyp verb install input version string "8.9.4"
gyp verb install installing version: 8.9.4
gyp verb install --ensure was passed, so won't reinstall if already installed
gyp verb install version not already installed, continuing with install 8.9.4
gyp verb ensuring nodedir is created /usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gyp/8.9.4
gyp WARN EACCES user "root" does not have permission to access the dev dir "/usr/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/node_modules/node-sass/.node-gy
```

how to solve this

Comment: Adding comment while question is closed.  I am running into the same error message.  I am on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS and just installed node 8.9.4 from https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x.  When I run `sudo npm install -g @angular/cli` the terminal scrolls forever on the install/reinstall of gyp.  Adding `--ignore-scripts` gets past the error, but I presume results in an incomplete install.

Comment: This seems to help:  `sudo npm install --ignore-scripts -g node-sass` `cd /usr/lib/node_modules/node-sass` `sudo npm run post-install` then reinstall @angular/cli.

Comment: I encountered this issue when trying to install the angular CLI with the LTS Version of Node (8.9.4) on MacOS (10.13.2). Switching to the most recent version of Node (9.4.0) did the trick for me.

Comment: Try to add `--unsafe-perm` to `install` command.